# My .env laravel file can be accessed by users at http: //localhost/ProjectLaravel/.env, I haven't found a solution for the .htaccess file

Tags: laravel-7

http: //localhost/ProjectLaravel/.env, I haven't found a solution for the .htaccess file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVSRn.png)

Comment: Point your webserver to the /public, not to the project directory

Comment: sorry, i mean, i will access my web without /public. Because if I host a user there is no need to access /public.
My url /public is missing, but on ulr I can access .env you can see in my image, me, I don't want that, and here I need to fill in the .htaccess file

Comment: can you show us what is in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I have included this question below

Answer (score 0):

My problem is finished. This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch "^\.env">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </FilesMatch>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```